# Unable to run Shell Script in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: java, shell, unit-testing, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to add below step in my pipeline but getting this error `illegal string body character after dollar sign; solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 33, column 75. td>Total<([^>]+>){4}([^<]*).*$/Missed in`

My Script is:

```
stage('Test Coverage'){
            steps {
                echo "Running test"
                sh "mvn test"
                script{
                    TOTAL_COVERAGE_STR = sh (
                    script: "sed -nE 's/^.*<td>Total<([^>]+>){4}([^<]*).*$/Missed instructions: \2/p' target/site/jacoco/index.html | tr -dc '0-9.0-9'",
                    returnStdout: true
                    ).trim()
                    THRESHOLD = 12.00
                    Float TOTAL_COVERAGE = TOTAL_COVERAGE_STR as Float
                    echo "Total Coverage : ${TOTAL_COVERAGE}, Threshold: ${THRESHOLD}"
                    if (THRESHOLD > TOTAL_COVERAGE) {
                        error('Aborting the build, as The Test Coverage Is Not As Expected')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried capturing the script inside single quotes also like this

```
'sed -nE 's/^.*<td>Total<([^>]+>){4}([^<]*).*$/Missed instructions: \2/p' target/site/jacoco/index.html | tr -dc '0-9.0-9''
```

in above case getting error: `unexpected token: s`

Comment: I'd recommend you move your shell script to its own file, even if it's "only" one line. The extra quoting in the pipeline description is messy, and you cannot use your usual tools like an IDE and shellcheck on it when it's embedded here. That said, I'd also first look for a tool that allows me to fail the build if coverage is under a certain threshold or has declined too much. You can't be the first one to want that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem while parsing the Regex. Maybe you can try setting regex syntax isolated inside a variable and using it inside your script:

`regexVal = /^.*<td>Total<([^>]+>){4}([^<]*).*$/`

*The leading and trailing slashed are needed if it contains variables to interpolate.*

So your script will be changed to something like this:

`'sed -nE 's/${regexVal}/Missed instructions: \2/p' target/site/jacoco/index.html | tr -dc '0-9.0-9''`